# Load interact.js just once

Tags: javascript, ajax, interact.js

I am using interact.js from here: [enter link description here](https://github.com/taye/interact.js)

The site where I am using it will be load over the Navigation ajax. The Problem here is, if the client click x times of the Navigation the interact.js will be loaded and loaded again. Normaly is shouldn´t be a problem, but I need to be sure the interact.js just load once.

Comment: Did you solve this. I am using angularjs and I cannot remove the interact event on next page load

Answer (score 0):

You can just put an `if(typeof interact === 'undefined')` before your call to the loading function. So if interact is loaded, the call will not be executed. Unfortunately you can't determine, if the loading process is still running. So while loading the process would be started a second time.

Comment: This is not working. He said interact is not defined. I´ve tried that:

if(typeof(interact) == "undefined")
 {
  var js        =  document.createElement("script");
   js.type      =  "text/javascript";
   js.src       =  "js/sonstige/interact.js";
  document.body.appendChild(js);
  console.log(interact);
 };

Comment: I see, this is not PHP ;-)
Yes, `if(typeof interact === 'undefined')` is better to check. I will edit this.
The call of `console.log(interact);` will most likely produce `ReferenceError: interact is not defined` on the first call, since interact is not yet loaded at this time.